# Displaying multiple nodes inside a single view block

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

I am somewhat new to drupal.

My goal is to display the 5 most recent nodes with a specific tag ("slideshow") in a, well, slideshow.

I am trying to use a views block in order to do that. But when I add the block to the main page, it shows nothing. I've also tried modifying the template 'archive' view, but it shows a link to a different page with the contents of a specific month instead of the posts themselves:

[image]

How can I have it so the content themselves are all displayed in this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new View (rather than trying to alter an existing one like Archive).
2. Add a Block display.
3. Set the "Number of items to display" to 5
4. Add filter(s) so that only the nodes you want are displayed
5. Add a sort by the created date of the node, descending, so the ones at the top of the list are the most recent.

Comment: Thanks man! I haven't been able to look deeper into why, but adding a new view from scratch solved my problem really easily

Comment: Sometimes starting fresh is a good way to overcome issues. Good luck! :-)